# Issues while lightweight Core Data Migration

Tags: swift, core-data

Hi I have a core data object which in previous version didnt have a unique constraint, but for now I need to add it (uuid field will be the constraint), but after imlementing lightweight migration all my data store becomes empty. Is there a way to implement lightweight migration for the constraint, or I need to make manual migration?